# Check each div and do action if condition is matched

Tags: jquery, html

I want to add some text inside a div if that div matches condition. Right now all the div's are filled up with the added text. Please check my code to better understand what I mean. 
What's the best solution to achieve my goal? Thank you.

```js
$('.col-md-3').each(function () {
    if ($('.status:contains("Rent")').length > 0) {
        $('.price').append('/month');
    };
    return false;
});
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3"><div class="status">Rent</div><div class="price">€100</div> 
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3"><div class="status">Rent</div><div class="price">€100</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3"><div class="status">For sale</div><div class="price">€1000</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3"><div class="status">For sale</div><div class="price">€1000</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why the `return false`? This will break the `.each()` after the first element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now you're telling jQuery to check every element in the document which has the class `.status`. You can pass a [context](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selector-context) which should be used to only look for elements matching the selector in this exact `<context>`.

---

[`jQuery( selector [, context ] )`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selector-context)

**selector**
Type: Selector
A string containing a selector expression

**context**
Type: Element or jQuery
A DOM Element, Document, or jQuery to use as context

---

In your example you have to use `this` as context as this is the current `.col-md-3`

```js
$(function() {
  $('.col-md-3').each(function() {
    if ($('.status:contains("Rent")', this).length > 0) {
      $('.price', this).append('/month');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3"><div class="status">Rent</div><div class="price">€100</div> 
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3"><div class="status">Rent</div><div class="price">€100</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3"><div class="status">For sale</div><div class="price">€1000</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3"><div class="status">For sale</div></div><div class="price">€1000</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

the problem with your code was in the condition
if ($('.status:contains("Rent")').length > 0) -> this was checking for all the status classes in the html which it then appends together. You might want to try checking for the problem
`alert($('.status:contains("Rent")'));`
`alert($('.status:contains("Rent")').length);`
        `$('.price').append('/month');` -> this was updating all the price classes which were present in the html even if the condition is true once.

jsfiddle link is here https://jsfiddle.net/hjd69qsf/2/

**the solution is as follows**

```
$('.col-md-3').each(function() {
  if ($(this).text().contains("Rent")) {
    $(this).children(".price").append('/month');
  };
});

<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="status">Rent</div>
    <div class="price">€100</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="status">Rent</div>
    <div class="price">€100</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="status">For sale</div>
    <div class="price">€1000</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="status">For sale</div>
    <div class="price">€1000</div>
  </div>
```